# Filter a 2d array by shared columns in another 2d array, then sum values in another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, intersection

How can I filter a 2d array by the shared column values in another array then sum the values in another column of the filtered data set?

```
$hotel = [
    [
        'name' => 'hotel one',
        'hotel_price' => '100',
        'hotel_child_price' => '50'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel two',
        'hotel_price' => '200',
        'hotel_child_price' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel three',
        'hotel_price' => '300',
        'hotel_child_price' => '200'
    ],
];

$user_selected_hotel = [
    [
        'name' => 'hotel one',
        'hotel_price' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel three',
        'hotel_price' => '300'
    ]
];
```

How can I retrieve from the first array the `hotel_child_price` which the user has selected meaning the sum of `50` and `200` = `250`.

The second array represents the user's hotel choice.

My current code:

```
foreach ( $user_selected_hotel as $lp => $hp) {
    $hotl_slct = $hp;
}

function searchForId($hotl_slct, $hotel) {
    foreach ($hotel as $cust1 => $cust_htl) {
        if ($cust_htl['name'] === $hotl_slct) {
            return $cust1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried that is not working as you expect it to.

Comment: How does that mean the user selected 200+50? I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to easily achieve your desired result, without `for` loops:

```
// Get hotel prices.
$prices = array_column($user_selected_hotel, 'hotel_price');
// Find those records from $hotel whose hotel prices are in prices.
$resultPrices = array_filter($hotel, function($elem) use ($prices) { return in_array($elem['hotel_price'], $prices);});
// Sum them.
$finalResult = array_sum(array_column($resultPrices, 'hotel_child_price'));
// Print result.
echo $finalResult;
```

An even shorter answer (in lines of code):

```
$resultPrices = array_filter($hotel, function($elem) use ($user_selected_hotel) { return in_array($elem['hotel_price'], array_column($user_selected_hotel, 'hotel_price'));});
$finalResult = array_sum(array_column($resultPrices, 'hotel_child_price'));
```

**Note**: Some of your data are missing `,`. Please consider correcting your sample data before running the above snippet.

Comment: I've used the array functions a lot and they are very useful.  But I've also realised they can often do a lot more work than is needed.  For example using `array_column()` will extract the data from all rows, even if you only end up searching the first few.

Comment: @NigelRen thank you for your remark, I wasn't aware of the overhead that `array_column` causes. I will try to improve my answer. But the logic implemented is that first you need to extract all values from `$hotel` and then filter them according to the values of `$user_selected_hotel` in order to get the final prices and sum them.

Comment: It's not about improving your answer - the answer is fine, it's just about being aware of the code your using and what it does in the background.

Comment: And just like that, me banging my head for 2 days straight without sleeping have paid off, You sir have solved the dilemma,Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected the source data (missing a few `,`'s), but the main thing is about how to find each record.

I've changed the `searchForId()` method to search for the record (using a simple `foreach()` and when found, it returns the array element for that name.  As it returns the array element, all it does then is to extract the `'hotel_child_price'` value and add it to a running total.

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $user_selected_hotel as $lp => $hp) {
    $total += searchForID($hp['name'], $hotel)['hotel_child_price'];
}
echo $total;

function searchForId($hotl_slct, $hotels ) {
    foreach ( $hotels as $hotel )   {
        if ( $hotel['name'] == $hotl_slct ) {
            return $hotel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understood what you want. But check if the following is what you are searching for, please:

```
$hotel = [
    [
        'name' => 'hotel one',
        'hotel_price' => '100',
        'hotel_child_price' => '50'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel two',
        'hotel_price' => '200',
        'hotel_child_price' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel three',
        'hotel_price' => '300',
        'hotel_child_price' => '200'
    ],
];

$user_selected_hotel = [
    [
        'name' => 'hotel one',
        'hotel_price' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'hotel three',
        'hotel_price' => '300'
    ]
];

foreach($user_selected_hotel as $selected) {
    $key = array_search($selected['name'], array_column($hotel, 'name'));
    $merge = array_merge($selected, $hotel[$key]);
    $merge['hotel_price'] = $selected['hotel_price'] + $hotel[$key]['hotel_price'];
    return $merge;
}
```

The line `$merge['hotel_price'] = $selected['hotel_price'] + $hotel[$key]['hotel_price'];` represents the sum between both 'hotel_price', from $hotel and $user_selected_hotel arrays.

Let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Value-based filtering in a functional style: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GmPY9))

```
var_export(
    array_sum(
        array_column(
            array_uintersect(
                $hotel,
                $user_selected_hotel,
                fn($a, $b) => $a['name'] <=> $b['name']
            ),
            'hotel_child_price'
        )
    )
);
```

Key-based filtering in a functional style: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/97Onk))

```
var_export(
    array_sum(
        array_intersect_key(
            array_column($hotel, 'hotel_child_price', 'name'),
            array_column($user_selected_hotel, null, 'name')
        )
    )
);
```

Foreach loop with selective row destructuring and a lookup array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pT4gH))

```
$lookup = array_column($hotel, 'hotel_child_price', 'name');
$sum = 0;
foreach ($user_selected_hotel as ['name' => $name]) {
    $sum += $lookup[$name];
}
var_export($sum);
```